# authentification of Ipython notebook using c.NotebookApp.login_handler_class parameter in config file

Tags: passwords, jupyter-notebook

I've setup a `Ipython 3.2.1 Notebook server`. However, I'm looking for a way to add our own authentication rule, which means I want to add my own authentication security authentication mechanism similar to `LDAP, OAuth` to notebook.

I don't want to use `JupyterHub`, since it's too complex for me to use. However,
I know from this site [two factor authentication with username and password for a Jupyter Notebook server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516906/two-factor-authentication-with-username-and-password-for-a-jupyter-notebook-serv?answertab=active#tab-top][1]) that we can deal with " The login handler class to use.

```
c.NotebookApp.login_handler_class = 'notebook.auth.login.LoginHandler'
```

in notebook configure file, but I don't know how to do it, do I need to write another `loginHandler` class to overwrite it? if so, which directory should I put this class file in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can modify the behavior of the `LoginHandler` by extending it. Something like the code below where I am overwriting the method `_render`.

```
    class MyLoginHandler(LoginHandler):
        def _render(self, message=None):
            # ... this is my custom code
```

Then you have to modify the Jupyter file to something like:

```
c.NotebookApp.login_handler_class = 'myModule.MyLoginHandler'
```